# How Muslims should deal with Islamophobia?

Tags: practical-islam, adab, non-muslim-countries

How should we as muslims should deal with the people who have these weird and perverted notions about Islam and our prophet muhammad(pbup).Especially those mainstream media literate people whose only source of information is "FOX" News, people who had never open a book in their lives let alone read them. What should we do, so they at least leave us alone..

Comment: As is this question is too broad and atracting opinion based answers. Please consider splitting it

Comment: @Medi1Saif  Can you help me to rephrase it?

Comment: Your question is a bit too complex. It can be answered -but as said many possible opinions would appear-. So maybe you should take a question on each topic, for example a false view on women in Islam, an other question a false view on let's say jihad and how one can deal with it. A maybe general answer is: Muslims should try to lead a Muslim live (being good to neighbors, do a good job etc.). If they had enough knowledge they should correct the false view. They should try to be a part of the country and community they live in not just a withdrawn group inside a group.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion brother, will keep those tips in mind next time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stay off of youtube comments below Islamic videos
2. Stop wasting their time / money on cable television
3. Pray to Allah swt for the patience to handle the opposition
4. Read about the Prophet and his companions and their struggles with the same issues.

Comment: This answer needs some elaboration. Please consider reading [answer].